# Get a specific word after pattern

Tags: python, string, split

I want to take the word 'desired' from the example below. How would I do that in python. Like what to do in the case of single line comments as shown below. I have tried something like print text.split(" ")[1] but it will only work in the case where there are no single line comments.

```
    text = /*   */
      The desired {word}
      /* */
```

Comment: What makes `desired` the special word?

Comment: @zondo, it is ***desired*** :D (no idea though, will let the asker respond)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/) and it's `ConcordanceIndex` to find surrounding words by an offset:

```
import nltk

text = """/*   */
  The desired word
  /* */"""

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

c = nltk.ConcordanceIndex(tokens)
print([tokens[offset - 1] for offset in c.offsets("word")])
```

Prints `['desired']`.